# Private sand box

Tags: feature-request

I want to write a very complex question/answer. It might take me few days to create. In the mean while, I want to continue using the site and asking/answering other not as complicated questions/answers.

Can we create a special storage for users, for that purpose, that latter they will be able to submit it as a question or an answer in their choice site and place.

Comment: You can't write these up using a word processor or other editor and post them when finished?

Comment: @Oded No, because my processor does not have stackexchange markdown formatting. Also I am usually not using the site from home, so I prefer things to be saved on the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You said to Oded:

> No, because my processor does not have stackexchange markdown
>   formatting

Fair enough, but you can use *any* online markdown editor.

[StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor#) is based on the library that SE's markdown editor uses - works exactly like Stack Exchange markdown.

> Also I am usually not using the site from home, so I prefer things to be saved on the site.

StackEdit allows you to save to Dropbox, Google Drive and CouchDB - so you can access it anywhere.

So, I really think this 'feature-request' is a lot of effort, for something that not many people will use, and if they want to, it can easily be done using other services!

Answer (score 7):

Math.SE has a [sandbox question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) on their meta.  Perhaps your site could adopt a similar custom.  The advantage of having only one sandbox question is that no matter how many times it gets bumped, it only takes up one slot on the front page of Meta.Math.SE.

Comment: The sandbox OP is referring to is to add a question or answer. The markdown sandbox doesn't seem very useful for that.

Comment: I don't get the issue.  Can't you do whatever you want in the markdown sandbox, then copy it over to the ask a question page?  Markdown is markdown.

Comment: what if people edit your post?

Comment: Tell them not to?  Revert it?  It works pretty well on Math.SE as far as I can tell.  If you have a higher percentage of jerks on your meta, results will probably not be as good.

Answer (score 6):

If you are preparing an question or answer, a draft is saved automatically if your browser supports it.

If you want to maintain multiple questions or answers, which seems *really unlikely* to me, you can use your own word processor. You can copy / paste it to / from an SE editor (or any online editor that supports Markdown) for the markup support if you want to.

I don't think it is useful for this one case to change the site.

Comment: How about stack-exchange will release their own editor that support their markdown. Because honestly this is the only thing that I need. Copy past is not so comfortable.

Comment: What about [this online markdown editor](http://dillinger.io/) (first hit)? I don't think SE does that much different than regular Markdown support.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think many people will use it *efficiently*, and there will be more than likely loads of *abandoned* questions and answers sat in storage doing nothing.
Then either storage is full up of pointless data, or we need some policy to *clean up*, such as inactive are deleted after X days, then we need some script to monitor and check if inactive, and something to store and check when last activity was, and so on.

For the *very small* potential usefulness this may bring to a *small* number of users, I just don't see it being worthwhile at all.

### You don't need to anyway:

You can use the markdown characters in a text document on your PC by wrapping the text in whatever markdown you want, which your editor shouldn't translate (basic editors won't).

For example, in your text editor type:
*I want italic*
**I want bold**

When you copy paste the above into Ask a Question or an Answer text area on a Stack Site, the above will be automatically converted and look like:
*I want italic*
**I want bold**

A header is just hyphens under a word, eg:

Some Header
----------

When pasted into Stack, it would again be automatically transformed into markdown and would look like:

### Some Header

Everything is the same, using bullet points is either:
Unordered list = 1 space, a hyphen, 1 space then your list text
Ordered list =  1 space, a number, a full stop (period), 1 space then your list text

Then proof read it to make sure it's formatted correctly, which you would do writing it on Stack anyway, if it's going to be a "very complex" question.